# Readiness Probe and Apache Common Http Client

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, readinessprobe

I have simple OpenShift setup with a Service configured with 2 backend PODS. The PODS have its READINESS Probe configured. The Service is exposed via NodePort. All these configuration are fine it is working as expected. Once the readiness probes fails the Services marks the pod as unreachable and any NEW requests don't get routed to the POD.

Scenario 1: 
I execute CURL command to access the services. While the curl command is executing I introduce readiness failure of Pod-1. I see that no new requests are sent to Pod -1. This is FINE

Scenario 2:
I hava Java Client and use Apache Commons Http Client library to initiate a connection to the Kubernetes Service. Connection gets established and it is working fine. The problem comes when I introduce readiness failure of Pod-1. I still see the Client sending requests to Pod-1 only, even though Services has only the endpoint of Pod-2.

My hunch, as the HttpClient uses Persistence Connection and Services when exposed via NodePorts, the destination address for the Http Connection is the POD-1 itself. So even if the readiness probe fails it still sends requests to Pod-1.

Can some one explain why this works they way described above ??

Answer (score 1):

kube-proxy (or rather the iptables rules it generates) intentionally does not shut down existing TCP connections when changing the endpoint mapping (which is what a failed readiness probe will trigger). This has been discussed a lot on many tickets over the years with generally little consensus on if the behavior should be changed. For now your best bet is to instead use an Ingress Controller for HTTP traffic, since those all update live and bypass kube-proxy. You could also send back a `Keep-Alive` header in your responses and terminate persistent connections after N seconds or requests, though that only shrinks the window for badness.